# assert pytest command has been run

Tags: python, pytest

I have an django app route that will run a pytest.main() command if some conditions are met:

```
def run_single_test(request, single_test_name):
    # get dict of test names, test paths
    test_dict = get_single_test_names()
    # check to see if test is in the dict
    if single_test_name in test_dict:
        for test_name,test_path in test_dict.items():
            # if testname is valid run associated test
            if test_name == single_test_name:
                os.chdir('/lib/tests/')
                run_test = pytest.main(['-v', '--json-report', test_path])
    else:
        return 'The requested test could not be found.'
```

I would like to include a unit test that validates `run_test` has been executed.

What is the best approach to doing this? Mock and unittest are new to me.

I tried messing around with stdout:

```
def test_run_single_test_flow_control(self):
        mock_get = patch('test_automation_app.views.get_single_test_names')
        mock_get = mock_get.start()
        mock_get.return_value = {'test_search': 'folder/test_file.py::TestClass::test'}

        results = run_single_test('this-request', 'test_search')
        output = sys.stdout
        self.assertEqual(output, '-v --json-report folder/test_file.py::TestClass::test')
```

but this returns:

```
<_pytest.capture.EncodedFile object at XXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
```

Comment: You can mock `pytest.main` and verify it was called with [`Mock.assert_called`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called) afterwards.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thank you.

Comment: I do not think I am doing this correctly. I created mock_pytest = patch('pytest.main') and then towards the added mock_get.assert_called. This will always pass so I must be implementing incorrectly.

Comment: When calling `mock_get.assert_called()`, you check that `get_single_test_names()` was called in the test; you need to use the correct mock to check whether `pytest.main` was invoked. I have added an answer that should give you an example of mocking and asserting the mock was invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two example tests that verify that `pytest.main` is invoked when a valid test name is passed and not invoked otherwise. I also added some different invocations of `mock_pytest_main.assert_called` as an example; they all do pretty much the same, with extra check for args that were passed on function call. Hope this helps you to write more complex tests!

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from test_automation_app.views import run_single_test


def test_pytest_invoked_when_test_name_valid():
    with patch('pytest.main') as mock_pytest_main, patch('test_automation_app.views.get_single_test_names') as mock_get:
        mock_get.return_value = {'test_search': 'folder/test_file.py::TestClass::test'}
        results = run_single_test('this-request', 'test_search')
        mock_pytest_main.assert_called()
        mock_pytest_main.assert_called_with(['-v', '--json-report', 'folder/test_file.py::TestClass::test'])
        mock_pytest_main.assert_called_once()
        mock_pytest_main.assert_called_once_with(['-v', '--json-report', 'folder/test_file.py::TestClass::test'])


def test_pytest_not_invoked_when_test_name_invalid():
    with patch('pytest.main') as mock_pytest_main, patch('test_automation_app.views.get_single_test_names') as mock_get:
        mock_get.return_value = {'test_search': 'folder/test_file.py::TestClass::test'}
        results = run_single_test('this-request', 'test_non_existent')
        mock_pytest_main.assert_not_called()
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this makes sense now. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Nice, glad I could help!